# Is Madara's Ten Tails Jinchuriki Mode a complete form?

Tags: naruto

Since Eight Tails is still outside (in dream) rather than in Gedo Statue, is Madara's Ten Tails Jinchuriki Mode complete?

Update:

I am talking about episode when Madara takes all the beasts into the Gedo statue and become the Sage of Six Paths. The Eight Tails was swapped with one of its tails to escape. As Eight Tails is not completely inside the Gedo statue, how can Madara come to Ten Tails Jinchuriki full form?

Comment: @labeo do you mean naruto in total? (also do "which" madara do you mean?) tried to formulate the comment in case you didn't watch the whole of naruto so far (as it seems you didn't).

Comment: I am talking about episode when madara takes all the beasts into the gedo statue and become sage of six paths but eight tails was swapped with one of its tail to escape as eight tails is not completely in gedo statue how can madara come to sage of six paths full form

Comment: Major correction: the form you are referring to is not the Sage of Six Paths mode. It is the Ten Tails Jinchuriki Mode. I've edited the correction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Madara's Ten Tails Jinchuriki Mode is complete.

The Gedo Statue drew in all the beasts.

When a Tailed Beast is removed from its host, the host dies. To avoid this from happening, there should be enough chakra of the Tailed Beast left inside the jinchuriki. When Gyuki was being removed, he sectioned one of his tentacles, having chakra, to Bee. This was done so to ensure Bee survives without the majority of [Gyuki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Gy%C5%ABki).

> Struggling against its confines, Gyūki apologised to B as it was extracted and sealed within the statue along with the other tailed beasts, but not before cutting off one of its tentacles, letting B survive through the chakra within it.

Therefore, the majority of Gyuki was absorbed into the statue and only a portion of it was intact with Bee. That portion served as a source of life for Bee and it was negligible compared to the intake of Eight Tails chakra into the statue.

Therefore, since the statue contained most of the Eight Tails chakra, Madara was able to undergo the transformation.

Comment: But half of nine tails is in naruto right?

Comment: Yes, first time Yang Kurama was sealed into Naruto. Then, when Yang Kurama was removed, Yin Kurama was sealed into Naruto from Minato.

Comment: So half can be considered as a measurable amount of chakra to tell that madara's ten tails form is not perfect?

Comment: To become the Ten Tails Jinchuriki, all you need is a considerable amount of chakra of the Tailed Beasts sealed into the Ten Tails. The question of excess or less doesn't seem to concern the jinchuriki form, as we can see that Obito was able to undergo the transformation even without the complete chakra of Kurama and Gyuki